# Different Behavior Depending on the Data

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's make it a simple example. Suppose I have a collection of `Number` objects, which can then be **even** or **odd**.

Suppose I want to traverse this collection and process each element. The process depends on the type of element: **even** or **odd**.

Example: Print each element, such that:

- if `Number` is even, I have **"This is an even number."**
- if `Number` is odd, I have **"This is an odd number."**

However, I may decide later that I want for *only the even numbers* to print **"An even number."**

So, as we see, this could be solved with *Inheritance* and *Polymorphism*, through the use of virtual functions:

```
class Number {/*...*/};              // base class
class Even : public Number {/*...*/} // derived class
class Odd  : public Number {/*...*/} // derived class
```

However, how can I provide the flexibility in the process to execute different behavior later on, as shown in the example above? Also, is there an alternative way to inheritance and polymorphism? Because I did not wanted to create inheritance tree only because of a specific computation/process.

The original problem is to execute different mathematical model depending on the type of an object, and the mathematical model is not unique for a given type of object (as the way I can print the even number is not unique).

---

**Edit:** It is funny that this post was closed with the argument that it is difficult to tell what is being asked. The authors of the several answers below seem to not agree with this, since all of them could understand it and reply what I was looking for.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  The example doesn't make sense.  `Even` and `Odd` are not very good data types or subclasses.  Nobody would create those classes to solve that problem (print "This is an (even/odd) number").  You should also specify what kind of flexibility you want to execute different behavior "later on".

Comment: Some ne might if they were trying to undertsand strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate your [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) hierarchy from the actual numbers. This way there is no need for an artificial class hierarchy, and you are free to change associations between number (value) types and actions even runtime. The association can be defined

- if you stick to the Number class hierarchy, then between Number subclass (Odd, Even) and strategy class (OddNumberStrategy, EvenNumberStrategy), or
- by a mapping between concrete values and strategy instances (of course this is suitable only if you have relatively few concrete values), or
- by a selector function.

As an alternative approach, you can redefine your Strategies as *handlers*, each of which can decide whether a given value is suitable for them to handle, and process them if so. Such handlers could even be chained or stored in a collection (and then iterated over for every value), such that some values can be processed by multiple "overlapping" handlers, if this suits you.

Comment: The Strategy Pattern is what I need and your answer reflects very well my problem. I don't want to create class hierarchy just because of a specific process among many. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use a [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):  have two classes EvenStrategy and OddStrategy, put the behavior in them, and add then to the Even and Odd classes at construction orm when you insert them in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this, but in general they all use *composition*. Let's take your example. Say we have an array of integers:

```
int foo[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Now, we want to print all the odd numbers from that:

```
void printIfOdd(int number) {
    if(number % 2 == 1)
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
}

std::for_each(foo, foo+10, printIfOdd);
```

We could do the same for even numbers. If you want to print both, you can compose the functions (which in this case is not in the mathematical sense of function composition):

```
template<class T>
class apply_all_functor {
public:
    apply_all_functor(T f1, T f2) : f1(f1), f2(f2) {}

    void operator()(int number) {
        f1(number);
        f2(number);
    }
private:
    T f1, f2;
};

template<class T>
apply_all_functor<T> apply_all(T f1, T f2) {
    return apply_all_functor<T>(f1, f2);
}

std::for_each(foo, foo+10, apply_all(printIfOdd, printIfEven);
```

The idea of composition can of course also be extended to objects, which gives rise to patterns like the [Strategy-Patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and the [Decorator-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You can see all full example of the code [here](http://ideone.com/fSQxo).